# Present modally when tab on tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to add a new tabbar item in my tabbar, and when tapping the item, the viewcontroller connected to it, should be displayed fullscreen and as a modal.

I have connected the desired VC to the tabbar as a root (in order for it to be displayed in the tabbar).

I have tried the following code, but the VC is displayed as normal behaviour for a tabbar viewcontroller.

How can I make it show modally fullscreen instead?

```
class tabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
            let isModalView = viewController is dreamteamViewController

            if isModalView {
                // you can refactor this part of the code
                let cameraController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dreamteamViewController())
                self.present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
```

Comment: is this delegate receiving in parentviewcontroller of the tab-bar?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad I have updated the question to show more code

Comment: I change self.tabBarController?.delegate = self with self?.delegate = self and it seems that it is working. Can you try it?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad still the same :(

Comment: I have added print's in the if isModalView, right before the return, and none of them is shown?

Comment: As I saw the delegate is not calling. and it seems that it is because that we are not setting the delegate instance to a correct receiver. I will try to post my project somewhere so that you can see it...

Comment: please check this project in my github https://github.com/Hbehboodi/Navigation-TabbarWithModalTabItem/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your viewDidLoad like this to set the delegate callback to correct instance:

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.delegate = self
   }
2. Define and storyboard identifier for your desired viewcontroller in the story board
3. Change your shouldSelect method like below:

   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool 
   {
           let isModalView = viewController is DesiredViewController

   ```
       if isModalView {
           // you can refactor this part of the code
           let mainStory = UIStoryboard(
               name: "Main", bundle: nil
           )
           let desiredVC = mainStory.instantiateViewController(
                   withIdentifier:"YourIdentifier"
               ) as UIViewController

           let navBar = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: desiredVC)


           self.present(navBar, animated: true, completion: nil)

           return false
       } else {
           return true
       }
   }
   ```

I posted a project in my github that present one of the tabbar item modally. Please check it from https://github.com/Hbehboodi/Navigation-TabbarWithModalTabItem if any thing is not clear.